# Wordpress paginate_links modify first link

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I modified paginate_links URL's to:

```
echo paginate_links(array('format' => 'page/%#%/#news'));
```

So that a user lands on the blog section again and not at the top of the website. Sadly the first link is ignored. Instead of `example.com/page/1/` it goes to `example.com/`. How could I change that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, you have to edit the 'base' attribut.

```
<?php  echo paginate_links( array(
'current' => max(1, get_query_var('paged')),
'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . 'page/%#%/#news',
'format' => 'page/%#%/#news',
));
```